# How can I upload a file from Outlook to Azure DevOps WorkItem using REST API and Microsoft Flow?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate, user-stories

I've created a Microsoft Flow, to triggered an event when Outlook email arrived, to create a new "User Story" WorkItem in Azure DevOps, attaching the files from Outlook to the Attachments tab.

```
Microsoft Flow "When a new email arrives" with the values,  
Importance Any, Has Attachment Yes and Include Attachments Yes.  
The next step is "Apply to each"
Select an output from previous steps: Attachments
"Send an HTTP Request to Azure DevOps"
Filling the required fields
Account Name: myaccountname
Method: POST
Relative URI: myprojectname/_apis/attachments?fileName=Attachments Name&api-version=5.0
Body: "[BINARY FILE CONTENT]"
```

("Attachments Name" is a dynamic content)

I've added a "Parse JSON"
Content: Current item
Schema:

The last step

```
"Create a new work item"
Account Name: myaccountname
Project Name: myproject
Work Item Type: User Story
Title: Subject
Description: Body
Other Fields
Enterkey field: System.AttachedFiles
Entervalue field: Attachments Name (dynamic content)
```

For the Schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ContentBytes": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ContentType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Size": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result: Attach the Outlook files to Azure DevOps User Story work item into the attachments tab.

Actual result: The file is not attached.

There is not an error message.
[First Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlYl8.png)

[Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfOzh.png)

[Last step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Pfx.png)

Comment: I just tried this and get this error "No fields found by the name 'System.AttachedFiles' in the work item type 'Task'". Not sure that helps, but I see you mentioning there is no error message when running this. I can see in the previous step that it is finding my attached file under System.AttachedFiles though.

Comment: I have resolved the issue using Sharepoint to add the files.

Comment: Could you outline what the process was that resolved this for you?